# Continuous memory increase when declaring very large array and iterating over stdin

Tags: memory, go

The following code declares two arrays, and then iterates over stdin ( just blindly iterates over the file - no interaction with the arrays ).

This is causing continuous increase in memory.

However, if I just declare two arrays and sleep - there is no increase in memory.

Similarly, if I just iterate over stdin - there is no increase in memory.

But together ( apart from the memory allocated for the arrays) there is a continuous increase.

I measure this by looking at the RES memory using top tool.

I have commented out the first few lines in `func doSomething()` to show that there is no memory increase when it is commented. Uncommenting the lines and running will cause an increase.

> NOTE: This was run on go 1.4.2, 1.5.3 and 1.6
>
> NOTE: You will need to recreate this on a machine with at least 16GB RAM as I have observed it only on the array size of 1 billion.

```go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    arr1 []int
    arr2 []int
}

func (ms *MyStruct) Init(size int, arr1 []int, arr2 []int) error {
    fmt.Printf("initializing mystruct arr1...\n")
    ms.arr1 = arr1
    if ms.arr1 == nil {
        ms.arr1 = make([]int, size, size)
    }
    fmt.Printf("initializing mystruct arr2...\n")
    ms.arr2 = arr2
    if ms.arr2 == nil {
        ms.arr2 = make([]int, size, size)
    }
    fmt.Printf("done initializing ...\n")
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        ms.arr1[i] = 0
        ms.arr2[i] = 0
    }
    return nil
}

func doSomething() error {
    fmt.Printf("starting...\n")
    fmt.Printf("allocating\n")
    /* NOTE WHEN UNCOMMENTED CAUSES MEMORY INCREASE 
    ms := &MyStruct{}
    size := 1000000000
    ms.Init(size, nil, nil)
    */

    fmt.Printf("finished allocating..%d %d\n", len(ms.arr1), len(ms.arr2))

    fmt.Printf("reading from stdin...\n")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    var line string
    var readErr error
    var lineNo int = 0
    for {
        if lineNo%1000000 == 0 {
            fmt.Printf("read %d lines...\n", lineNo)
        }
        lineNo++

        line, readErr = reader.ReadString('\n')
        if readErr != nil {
            fmt.Printf("break at %s\n", line)
            break
        }
    }

    if readErr == io.EOF {
        readErr = nil
    }

    if readErr != nil {
        return readErr
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    if err := doSomething(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("done...\n")
}
```

1. Is this an issue with my code ? Or is the go system doing something unintended ?
2. If its the latter, how can I go about debugging this ?

To make it easier to replicate here are pastebin files for good case ( commented portion of the above code) and bad case ( with uncommented portion )

```bash
wget http://pastebin.com/raw/QfG22xXk -O badcase.go
yes "1234567890" | go run badcase.go

wget http://pastebin.com/raw/G9xS2fKy -O goodcase.go
yes "1234567890" | go run goodcase.go
```

Comment: How do you measure "increase of memory" and which type of memory are you talking about. Most probably everything is fine; skimming your code it looks okay. And of course your code will consume more memory if you allocate 2 billion ints as this is 8 GByte at least.

Comment: @Volker I start a htop and monitor RES memory. Yes, on a 64 bit machine it takes around 16 GB at startup, but the moment I start reading from stdin it shoots up and never stops . (Updated question to reflect comment as well ).

Comment: Are you sure it really doesn't stop? To take a look at memory follow http://dave.cheney.net/2015/11/29/a-whirlwind-tour-of-gos-runtime-environment-variables especially GODEBUG and gctrace which is much more helpful than (h)top

Comment: @Volker  just to confirm - a continuous increase in RES for this process establishes the fact that memory is increasing. I will have to use godebug and gctrace to find out the reason for it right ? Also, "doesn't really stop" is what I assumed when it increased from 16 (what it is supposed to be )  to 32 gigs ( my ram limit ) after which it went into swap so I killed it.

Comment: Not necessarily. The concept of "memory" is complicated, e.g. Go reservers large junks but may not use it and may or may not return them to the OS which is unproblematic. What's definitively "wrong" with your code that you allocate 2*8GByte of continuous memory but your machine has just 32GByte: You pin 50% of the total RAM for two very large (but completely unused) int slices. As you did not state why you do this I'd just recommend to simply not do this (or use much shorter slices or a different data structure which doesn't need continuous memory).

Comment: To see what is going on and what Go does with the memory given to it from the OS htop is insufficient. Use GODEBUG="gctrace=1" to see "inside" Go's garbage collector. Probably you'll find that GC doesn't run "often enough": The default for GOGC is 100 which means GC is not triggered until the heap has doubled. Probably heap doubling happens very late as you block 16GByte initially: Maybe GC doesn't kick in until 32 GByte are used which is too much for your machine. Either reduce GOGC (e.g. to 25) or as said above: To not pin 16 GByte of continuous memory into your 32GByte RAM.

Comment: @volker thank you . I shall try the gctrace and gogc  as I require the 2 continuous arrays for Union find on one billion numbers. Will post my findings here.

Comment: @Volker that did the trick ! I've captured it in an answer for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you [Volker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266756/volker) for your above comments. I wanted to capture the process of debugging this as an answer.

The RES `top / htop` just tells you at a process level what is going on with memory. GODEBUG="gctrace=1" gives you more insight into how the memory is being handled.

A simple run with gctrace set gives the following

```
root@localhost ~ # yes "12345678901234567890123456789012" | GODEBUG="gctrace=1" go run badcase.go
starting...
allocating
initializing mystruct arr1...
initializing mystruct arr2...
gc 1 @0.050s 0%: 0.19+0.23+0.068 ms clock, 0.58+0.016/0.16/0.25+0.20 ms cpu, 7629->7629->7629 MB, 7630 MB goal, 8 P
done initializing ...
gc 2 @0.100s 0%: 0.070+2515+0.23 ms clock, 0.49+0.025/0.096/0.24+1.6finished allocating..1000000000 1000000000
 ms cpu, 15258->15258reading from stdin...
->15258 MB, 15259read 0 lines...
 MB goal, 8 P
gc 3 @2.620s 0%: 0.009+0.32+0.23 ms clock, 0.072+0/0.20/0.11+1.8 ms cpu, 15259->15259->15258 MB, 30517 MB goal, 8 P

read 1000000 lines...
read 2000000 lines...
read 3000000 lines...
read 4000000 lines...
....
read 51000000 lines...
read 52000000 lines...
read 53000000 lines...
read 54000000 lines...
```

> What does this mean ?

As you can see, the gc hasn't been called for a while now. This means that all the garbage generated from reader.ReadString hasn't been collected and free'd.

> Why isn't the garbage collector collecting this garbage ?

From [The go gc](https://blog.golang.org/go15gc)

> Instead we provide a single knob, called GOGC. This value controls
>   the total size of the heap relative to the size of reachable objects.
>   The default value of 100 means that total heap size is now 100% bigger
>   than (i.e., twice) the size of the reachable objects after the last
>   collection.

Since GOGC wasn't set - the default was 100%. So, it would have collected the garbage only when it reached ~32GB. ( Since initially the two arrays give you 16GB of heap space - only when heap doubles will the gc trigger ).

> How can I change this ?
>   Try setting the GOGC=25.

With the GOGC as 25

```
root@localhost ~ # yes "12345678901234567890123456789012" | GODEBUG="gctrace=1" GOGC=25 go run badcase.go
starting...
allocating
initializing mystruct arr1...
initializing mystruct arr2...
gc 1 @0.051s 0%: 0.14+0.30+0.11 ms clock, 0.42+0.016/0.31/0.094+0.35 ms cpu, 7629->7629->7629 MB, 7630 MB goal, 8 P
done initializing ...
finished allocating..1000000000 1000000000
gc 2 @0.102s reading from stdin...
12%: 0.058+2480+0.26 ms clock, 0.40+0.022/2480/0.10+1.8 ms cpu, 15258->15258->15258 MB, 15259 MB goal, 8 P
read 0 lines...
gc 3 @2.584s 12%: 0.009+0.20+0.22 ms clock, 0.075+0/0.24/0.046+1.8 ms cpu, 15259->15259->15258 MB, 19073 MB goal, 8 P
read 1000000 lines...
read 2000000 lines...
read 3000000 lines...
read 4000000 lines...
....
read 19000000 lines...
read 20000000 lines...
gc 4 @6.539s 4%: 0.019+2.3+0.23 ms clock, 0.15+0/2.1/12+1.8 ms cpu, 17166->17166->15258 MB, 19073 MB goal, 8 P
```

As you can see, another gc was triggered.

> But top/htop shows it stable at ~20 GB instead of the calculated 16GB.

The garbage collector doesn't "have" to give it back to the OS. It will sometimes keep it to use efficiently for the future. It doesn't have to keep taking from the OS and giving back - The extra 4 gb is in its pool of free space to use before asking the OS again.

Comment: @Volker thank you for all the help. I've tried to capture it as best I can in this answer. If you have anything more useful to add feel free to edit !